# Tabelas HTML5 - subdividir coluna

Tags: html5

Preciso sudividir o TD das colunas Etapas e Circuitos em duas partes.
A idéia é que apareça no TH a palavra "Etapas" e os valores inseridos nessa coluna serão divididos em <30 e > 30.

```
 Etapas
<30   >30
 1      2
 5      6
```

Como faço essa subdivisão semanticamente? Estou usando o bootstrap para fazer o layout.

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Fase
                </th>

                <th>
                    Descricão
                </th>
                <th>
                    Etapas
                </th>
                <th>
                    Circuitos
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve usar o [`colspan` e `rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) para mesclar as colunas que necessitar, e criar uma sublinha `<tr>` para os subtítulos das colunas. Algo similar a isso:

```html
<div>
    <table border="1px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Fase</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Descricão</th>
                <th colspan="2">Etapas</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Circuitos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>>30</th>
                <th><30</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>valores > 30</td>
                <td>valores < 30</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Explicação da solução:**

- Extendemos as celulas de titulo que não contém subtitulo em 2
  `rowspan`, ou seja, informamos que está celula irá ocupar o espaço de 2
  *rows*;
- Extendemos as celulas de titulo que contém subtitulo para a
  quantidade de subtitulos que ele terá, em nosso caso 2 `colspan`, ou
  seja, informamos que está celula irá ocupar o espaço de 2 *columns*;
- Por fim, criamos uma nova *row* (`<tr>`) para os subtitulos, onde ele irá
  se alocar nas *columns* que não foram ocupados por `rowspan`, em nosso
  caso as 3° e 4° colunas;

**Conceitos:**

- **`colspan`**: Este atributo contém um valor inteiro não negativo que indica em quantas colunas a célula se estende. Seu valor padrão é 1;
  se o seu valor for definido como 0, este se estende até o final do
  , eventualmente definido implicitamente, a célula pertence.
  Valores superiores a 1000 são truncados até 1000.*¹
- **`rowspan`**: Este atributo contém um valor inteiro não negativo que indica em quantas linhas a célula se estende. Seu valor padrão é 1;
  se o seu valor for definido como 0, este se estende até o final da
  seção de `table` (`<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, eventualmente
  definido implicitamente) a célula pertence. Valores maiores que 65534
  são truncados para baixo para 65534.*¹

> <sup>*¹Tradução da definação de `rowspan` e `colspan` do MDN. [Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar o `colspan` que mescla 2 ou mais colunas:

```html
<div>
    <table border="1px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fase</th>
                <th>Descricão</th>
                <th colspan="2">Etapas</th>
                <th colspan="2">Circuitos</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>< 30</td>
                <td>> 30</td>
                <td>< 30</td>
                <td>> 30</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```