# Duas celulas de dados para uma de cabeçalho

Tags: html

Como posso criar uma tabela onde tenho dois `td` para um só `th`, exemplo:

```
| Tabela Exemplo  | Exemplo |
| parte1 | parte2 |         |
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tabelas HTML5 - subdividir coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46653/tabelas-html5-subdividir-coluna)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para expandir uma célula da tabela vc precisa usar o atributo `colspan`. Lembro que `colspan` é para expandir a coluna, e `rowspan` é para estender a linha. Se vc quer que a coluna se estenda por duas células, vc coloca `colspan="2"`

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
    <td>normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Agora com rowspan</p>
<table>
  <tr>
<td>01</td>
<td rowspan="2">rowspan="2"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>02</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu concordo plenamente com a resposta do @hugocsl, só que acho que dá pra esclarecer um pouco melhor como os atributos `colspan` e `rowspan` funcionam.

Com uma pequena alteração, adicionando o `rowspan` dá pra ocupar mais de uma linha também, e o valor também pode ser maior que dois, de acordo com sua necessidade.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> Tabela Exemplo </td>
    <td> Exemplo </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"> parte 1 </td>
    <td> parte 2 </td>
    <td> parte 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> parte 2 </td>
    <td> parte 3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Você pode misturar os dois atributos também, para que uma célula, ocupa mais de uma linha e mais de uma coluna! :)

Referência:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp